# CSS Inline-block rounding error?

Tags: html, css

This isn't the traditional where is the whitespace coming from question, but rather where is this extra pixel coming from and how can I stop it?

The code below produces a container that is a third of the available width, within it there is a list split into 3 , the list has the width set to 100% as do the children, the children are inline-blocks all stacked next to each other and only the first is show (due to overflow on the container).

The issue is that at varying screen widths one of the list elements becomes a pixel smaller/larger than the other two? I can't get my head around this as they are supposed to be expanding to the width of their parent - which is the same for all three list items.

Is this an issue with my approach or a bug, is there a fix?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    display:block;
    width:33.333%;
}

.list {
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-size:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.list li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background:blue;
    border: 1px dashed yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e6z218n7/

**UPDATED**

Just to add my thinking/expections;

- Say the body of the page is 821px,
- The .container element at 33.333% should come about at 274px or 273px depending on how the browser rounds,
- In either of these cases I'd expect each of the li's to come out at the same width as their parent as they have width:100% so each li should also be 274px or 273px (depending on which the parent is) which should only be relative to their parent right?

Of course this is not what I'm getting, and I'm not understanding why?

Comment: When a number (screen width) isn't perfectly divisible by 3, you can't have pixel-perfect widths...Think about it. It's just math/remainders.

Comment: Well I'm not quite after pixel perfect widths, I just want children to inherit the exact same width as their parent? This seems like a fair assumption that it would just work

Comment: but do you want to make 3 <li>'s that are thirds of <ul> or not? If the <li>'s had the same with of their parent they would all be 100% wouldn't they?

Comment: the <li>'s should not be thirds, but each be the same width as the containing element, so the <li>'s are not thirds, the only element that should be a third is the .container, whats not clicking with me is that the relationship between <div class="list"> and each of the <li>'s is different when they are all children. I get the Math, I just don't understand why it's happening?

Answer (score 2):

If the width is set to 100% and it isn't equally divisible by 3 ... naturally the extra pixel will be assigned to one of the divs.

Example

> The width is 445px ... if you divide it by 3 it will give 148,333px
>   ... this means that 2 divs will have 148px and the other will have
>   149px

You can't work around this using only HTML+CSS ... but you can achieve a pixel-perfect approach if you use JS/jQuery.

If you're interested in the jQuery approach ... add this to your project and include jQuery lib.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e6z218n7/1/)

```
function calcDivW() {
    var w = parseInt(($(window).width()-10)/3);

$('.list > li').css('width',w);

}

$(function(){
    calcDivW();
});

$(window).on('resize',function(){
calcDivW();
});
```

**UPDATE**

This fiddle shows what you're describing in the bottom of the OP.

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e6z218n7/4/)

.container has 33% and is one third of window size;
.list has 100% and so is 100% of .container;
.li has 100% so each li is 100% of .list (or .container because .container and .list have the same width)

Everything seems to be as it should.

Comment: See that makes sense, but the problem isn't splitting the three children into thirds, they are essentially all supposed to make up the initial thrid which is one width, I'm not fussed about the second and third thirds of the page, if that makes sense?

Comment: although you set width to be 33,333% in your css ... the browser parses pixel units and calculates the div width as I told you in the example above.

Comment: Thanks for the jQuery option, that is essentially the result i'm aiming for, but isn't it overkill to use jQuery for a problem like this surely there must be a css solution?

Comment: .container has 33% and is one third of window size as it should; .list has 100% and so is 100% of .container as it should; .li has 100% so each li is 100% of .list (or .container because .container and .list have the same width) as it should ... i don't see any erratic behaviour ... see http://jsfiddle.net/e6z218n7/4/